# Python differentiation using numpy not producing expected output

Tags: python, numpy, math, derivative

So, I am working on some numerical computation. I have calculated some 100,000 points of a function (`return_times`) only computable numerically, and now want to take it's derivate using `numpy.gradient`. As I understand ([doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)), for an f(x)I can give the following arguments: `numpy.gradient(arr_of_fx_datapoints, arr_of_their_x_values)` to make it work. And that's what I (intended to) do.

Except that it doesn't work. The result is almost (but not exactly) zero everywhere. The bug is reproduced by this abstract of my code below (sin^2(x) has a shape alike to my original function):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def find_times(t_arr):
    return np.power(np.sin(t_arr), 2)

t_0 = 0
t_max = np.pi-1E-10
datapoints = 100000

dt = (t_max - t_0) / datapoints
t_points = np.arange(t_0, t_max, dt, dtype=np.float64)
return_times = find_times(t_points)
gd = np.gradient(return_times, t_points)
plt.plot(t_points, gd)
plt.plot(t_points, return_times)
plt.show()
```

The result is disappointing:
[image]

If I print `gd`, it shows it is indeed not entriely zero:

```
[             inf   6.28318530e-05   6.28318529e-05 ...,  -1.25666419e-09
  -6.28326813e-10  -3.14161265e-10]
```

So: What did I miss? What is the Ultimate Proper Way to numerically derivate in Python?

Enviroment: Linux Mint 18.2 OS, Geany editor, NumPy 1.11.0.

Comment: Your code made a different plot for me, non-zero indeed

Comment: @dermen how on earth?... I literally pasted the full code 10 sec after I got this image from it, whithout any change. What's going on??

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. While I don't have matplotlib and can't plot the result, `gd` has the expected gradient values for me, and `gd.max()` is about 1.

Comment: How are you executing the above code to produce the plot ?

Comment: If you are using interactive python, close the session, reopen it and re-paste

Comment: @dermen Using Geany. It should simply execute `python [filename]`.

Comment: I suspect the problem is going to go away in a clean session and we'll end up closing this as "can no longer be reproduced" while you try to figure out what the original problem was.

Comment: It raised "ValueError: distances must be scalars" for me in the gradient call. (Python 3.6, numpy 1.12.1)

Comment: @user2357112 I'll try this after a reboot. I'm afraid I'm not the right person for hunting down such a strange problem though... let's hope.

Comment: @ayhan I also have SciPy installed, though not imported. My NumPy came with it. Version 1.11.0.

Comment: @ayhan: It looks like the coordinate array support is very new, NumPy 1.13. The 1.12 docs don't have it.

Comment: @Neinstein: NumPy 1.11.0? Try upgrading. The coordinate array support isn't mentioned in the docs pre-1.13; it may be silently doing the wrong thing on pre-1.12 versions.

Comment: ([1.12 docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html), with no mention of coordinate array support.)

Comment: @user2357112 Yes it resolved when I upgraded http://imgur.com/a/M3s5u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs don't mention it, but coordinate array support is very new, NumPy 1.13. In previous NumPy versions, you can only specify a fixed scalar step value for each dimension.

NumPy 1.12 has a check to catch non-scalar steps, but NumPy 1.11, which you're on, doesn't notice the array-valued input and silently does the wrong thing by trying to treat the array as a step.