# numpy gradient() behaves differently between versions

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I noticed this when searching around `numpy.gradient()` usages. It seems that since numpy 1.13, the function treats it input argument differently than previous versions. Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
y=np.sin(x)

dx=np.gradient(x)

grad1=np.gradient(y,dx)
print grad1

grad2=np.gradient(y,x)
print grad2
```

I tested in numpy 1.13 and 1.11.3.

In 1.13, `gradient(array1, array2)` treats `array2` as coordinates (x) for `array1`. But in 1.11.3, it treats `array2` as the differentiation of coordinates (dx). So `grad1` works in 1.11.3, and `grad2` works for 1.13.

I think this is a rather dangeous trap, people may get wrong results if the same code is run using different versions of numpy. Or am I missing something obvious that clears this ambiguity?

Comment: `numpy.gradient` never supported an array for arguments after the first, pre-1.13. The fact that it didn't raise an exception was unfortunate, but they weren't checking.

Comment: @user2357112 So what's the best option at the moment? I need to do some gradient calculation with non-evenly spaced coordinates.

Comment: I think I'll just do the dy and dx myself and the gradient as dy/dx, that will be the same in both versions.

Comment: @Jason: Your best option is to require `numpy >= 1.13`, which is the first version to support unevenly-spaced coordinates. If that's not an option, then you could copy the 1.13 source code for that function, and include it in your project

Comment: It turns out that I'm not the first falling into this trap, here is another related question (possibly duplicating his): https://stackoverflow.com/q/45776214/2005415.

Comment: @user2357112 I think in 1.11.3 at least you can give a 2nd array argument specifying the spacing. See the example in the doc_string.

Comment: @Jason: When it says "scalar or list of scalar", it's saying you can provide one scalar step that applies to all dimensions or a separate scalar step for each dimension; you can't pass an array. ("list of scalar" is probably not the right terminology.)

Comment: @user2357112 Yeh I know. Why don't you just open a python and test it