# Creating a complex custom loss in Keras for a seq2seq problem

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss

I would like to write a custom loss function for a seq2seq problem.
My input (X) has shape (N, M), that is, N sequences of length M each. Each sequence has M/2 numbers (from 1 to M/2), repeated twice and randomly. Here, is an example with M=200:

```
X = array([[ 60.,  71.,  15., ...,  73.,  64.,  71.],
       [ 71.,  37.,  19., ...,  78.,  34.,  65.],
       [ 50.,  41.,  91., ...,  57.,  59.,   4.],
       ...,
       [  2.,  66.,  79., ...,  25.,  66.,  13.],
       [ 16.,  25.,  11., ...,  83.,  74.,  38.],
       [ 73., 100.,  91., ...,  48.,  61.,  51.]])
```

```
y = array([[1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

I reshape them to

```
X_ = X.reshape(X.shape[0],1,X.shape[1])
y_ = y.reshape(y.shape[0],1,y.shape[1])
```

I would like that the loss is calculated based on the number of times there is a change in the y_pred (and y) sequences. For instance, if my output is y_pred = [ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ], the number of times there is a change from 0 to 1 (or viceversa) is 4.

Here is my network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(400,input_shape =(1,X_.shape[2]), activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(350,activation='relu',return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=my_loss_fn, optimizer='Adam')
```

And this is the loss function I tried to write:

```
def my_loss_fn(y, y_pred):
    import tensorflow as tf
    c1 = tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.experimental.numpy.diff(y)!=0)
    c2 = tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.experimental.numpy.diff(y_pred)!=0)
    return tf.math.subtract(c1, c2)
```

The problem is that I get this error when I fit the model:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable
```

This happens most probably because numpy.diff is not differentiable as pointed out here ([Numpy or SciPy Derivative function for non-uniform spacing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875253/numpy-or-scipy-derivative-function-for-non-uniform-spacing)) and here (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/differentiable-version-of-numpy-diff/89347/4).

How could I create a differentiable version of my function?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I needed to use differentiable operations. I found a list of differentiable operations in Tensorflow (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops) and modified the custom loss function accordingly:

```
def loss_fn(y_true, y_):
    a1 = tf.roll(y_true, shift=1, axis=1)
    c1 = tf.subtract(a1, y_true)
    
    a2 = tf.roll(y_, shift=1, axis=1)
    c2 = tf.subtract(a1, y_)
    
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(c1 - c2))
```